# 3 Dimensional Database in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have a question. how do I store 3 dimensional data?
This is an example. Every user should fill this field.

[2 Dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YikC4.png)

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to discover which users don't know their family members' birthday? Why would you store all that in 3D? If Joe is Jane's dad, Joe's birthday should be the same as Jane's father's birthday. Just have a `person` table (with `mother` and `father` foreign keys); or if you want to model more complex relationships, another `relation` table with two foreign keys and a relationship field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by using three related tables:

- User
- RelativeType
- UserRelativeInfo

They would be related like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You create another table with foreign key references. For more dimensions, add more tables:

```
Devices
| deviceId | device | location |  
| 1        | xx     | aa       |
| 2        | yy     | bb       |
| 3        | zz     | cc       |
```

```
Sensor
| sensorId | deviceId | Type   |  
| 1        | 1        | temp   |
| 2        | 1        | rpm    |
| 3        | 2        | temp   |
```

```
Data
| dataId | sensorId | value  | timestamp        |   
| 1      | 1        | 10     | 2020-01-01 00:00 |
| 2      | 1        | 10     | 2020-01-01 01:00 |
| 3      | 1        | 11     | 2020-01-01 02:00 |
| 4      | 1        | 12     | 2020-01-01 03:00 |
| 5      | 2        | 3100   | 2020-01-01 01:00 |
| 6      | 2        | 3200   | 2020-01-01 02:00 |
| 7      | 3        | 23     | 2020-01-01 01:00 |
| 8      | 3        | 23     | 2020-01-01 02:00 |
```